# how to align QLCDNumber right?

Tags: qt, lcd

When adding a QLCDNumber to a form it seems to always center in its container box. Is there a way to align the numbers to the right or left?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try putting a spacer before it see [this link](http://www.ffuts.org/blog/right-aligning-a-button-in-a-qtoolbar/)

```
spacer = QWidget()
spacer.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
# hbox is an existing QHboxLayout
# lcdnumber is an existing QLCDNumber
hbox.addWidget(spacer)
hbox.addWidget(lcdnumber)
```